# Visual Studio 2008 version specific references

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know if Visual Studio 2008 has a mechianism in web applications to include a reference without it being version specific?

Backstory:
I have a new web application built in VS08 which references class libraries built in VS03. The class library DLLs are included in a \References folder within the VS08 project. The references are version specific, this is what I see in the VS08 .proj file:

The class library is built once a day through CruiseControl so I need to manually update the DLLs and version numbers in VS08 once the build finishes.

I'm looking to automate this. Updating the DLLs in our repository isn't a problem, but making a build script to parse apart the .proj file and update the version number isn't optimal, but it's a hack that would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but it's one approach of managing this problem:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ManagingAssemblyVersions.aspx

It uses this tool.

http://code.mattgriffith.net/UpdateVersion/

The UpdateVersion tool can be used to automatically update your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to use a versioning system that's more friendly to practices such as daily builds.